# OptionalValidatorFactoryBean - Spring Multiple Beans instantiated - multi module Maven project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am facing an issue with spring boot (2.3.4.RELEASE) application failing to load the context. This is happening while it is trying to inject an instance of `javax.validator.Validator` interface.

The reason is, there are multiple instances of the implementation class `org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean` resulting in `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException`

I am unable to trace how the same bean is instantiated 4 times, though I can print the list of beans in application context and see all four named as
`OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0` through `OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#4`.

Since I am unable to provide the whole dependency tree here, I am providing a few dependencies which we import and I think are related to the Validation injection

- spring-context 5.2.9.RELEASE
- hibernate-validator 6.1.5.FINAL
- jakarta.validation-api 2.0.2

Since this is a Spring API class and the dependency injection is taking place in another API class that we import, I am unable to use `@Qualifier` or `@Primary`. Hence I am looking to find out and fix the source of multiple instantiation. Unfortunately, I am unable to provide lot of information due to proprietary issues. Can anyone help with how I can proceed, as I almost spent a day debugging to find out this information and couldn't find much info.

Comment: Are you using maven for dependency management? Have you tried to exclude dependencies that are causing the conflict?

Comment: We use maven. But the class that is instantiated multiple times comes only from one jar (spring-context) and there is only one version of this jar that is resolved. During loading of application context, spring instantiates multiple instances of the same class may be from multiple modules. I am trying to find a way from where these instantiations happen, so that I can remove those. I don't think we can remove any of these dependencies that I mentioned here

Comment: Update - Solved by declaring a new Primary Bean of same type in custom config class. Still interested in knowing if we can see hierarchy in which spring loads bean instances

Comment: You are using Spring Boot but list individual validation jars, which is weird. You should use the `spring-boot-starter-validation` which includes the necessary validation dependencies. The same applies to the `spring-context` dependency that is already pulled in differently. The class that is being instantiated multiple times shouldn't happen and probably is due to some configuration you are doing yourself (importing it, using another framework etc.). So without seeing your actual configuration for your application what is causing this is impossible to answer.

Comment: Thanks. I listed out the individual jars since I see these jars are used as part of validation. Problem is this is an existing multi module maven app and the dependencies are a mess. So one way for me is to analyze the tree and do a clean up, which I did to an extend. Right now, for the issue with multiple beans, I was able to define a new @Primary bean. As I mentioned, I am helpless exporting the configuration from work network.